# Methods inside onPlaceSelected are not executed

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to execute search method inside onPlaceSelected. Method is not executed. When I write code directly inside onPlaceSelected it works.

```
fun search(latLng: LatLng?){
        dispose = weatherApiService
                .requestHourlyWeather(latLng!!.latitude, latLng!!.longitude, client_id, client_secret)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        {result -> Log.d("Search result:", result.response[0].periods[0].tempC.toString())},
                        { error -> Log.d("Searching error", error.message)}
                )
    }


override fun onPlaceSelected(p0: Place?) {
    search(p0?.latLng) //is not executed, but if I place code directly here it is working

}
```

Is there a way to perform action after onPlaceSelected is called and pass just searching result? Example: wait for onPlaceSelected is called -> pass data and start searching?

Answer (score 0):

I set up listener inside oncreate and now all is working fine.

```
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(object: PlaceSelectionListener
```